# Ресурс Laravel, добавить в конец

Tags: php, json, laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста второй день бьюсь, есть ресурс в которую приходит коллекция, как мне в конец массива добавить еще один объект

В моделе

```
 $users = User::all();
 return UsersAllResource::collection($users);

<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Auth;
use Cache;
use Gate;


class UsersAllResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'            => $this->id,
            'name'          => $this->name,
            'surname'       => $this->surname,
            'online'        => Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $this->id),
        ];
    }
}
```

Как добавить в конец еще один массив, пробовал так но не помогает

```
public function with($request)
    {
        return [
            'can' => [
                'user_delete'       => Gate::allows('user_delete', $this->resource),
                'user_show'         => Gate::allows('user_show', $this->resource),
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Через сеттеры? Через модификаторы? Это как варианты